# How to send images from cordova-vuejs app to whatsapp?

Tags: cordova, vue.js, vuejs2, cordova-plugins

I am using codova and vuejs for making hybrid app. I want to integrate whatsapp in my app to send images from my app to whatsapp. How can we able to do it?

Comment: Can you provide details about what you have already tried so far?

Comment: I have tried whatsapp api integration but it does not allows us to send images from app.

Answer (score 1):

To share picture, i use cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing

To install the plugin :

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing
```

To share content to whatsapp :

```
<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaWhatsApp('Message via WhatsApp', null /* img */, null /* url */, function() {console.log('share ok')}, function(errormsg){alert(errormsg)})">msg via WhatsApp (with errcallback)</button>
```

Source :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing

Comment: How can we send image from vuejs code to cordova function ?

Comment: in my case the image is saved on my server, then i share just the url of the pic